# How to Display a Different Facebook Caption from URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

What I mean by caption is the "KDAVKDAV.COM" below the description.

I want to change it to other words, like, GOOGLE.COM.

[image]

When I try to post this url http://kdavkdav.com/2016/01/07/xxxxx/

Facebook fetched meta tag in the `<head>` tag below to produce info as the pic shows above.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:description" content="Description">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB">
<meta property="og:title" content="Coaches Wisdom Telesummit" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb" />
<meta property="og:url" content="GOOGLE.COM" />
```

I know this is possible, because of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCcPfPVRVKk from 1:40 minutes and the result stops at 2:46 minutes

Thank you

Comment: `og:url` is the URL that Facebook will try and fetch the meta data from. Setting it to `GOOGLE.COM` therefor makes no sense whatsoever (unless you wanted to share the Google page, and not yours.)

Comment: I want them to see the link from google but end up redirecting to a different page. It's good for an affiliate.

Comment: For example, you can share a news from CNN then it redirects to your affiliate site. ;)

Comment: If you set `og:url` to a URL X, then Facebook will make a request for X, and use the meta data it finds there. If you want it to use _your_ meta data, then `og:url` has to point to _your_ URL. (You can of course redirect human visitors that click on that link and then land on your URL, to some place else afterwards – either client-side via JS, or server-side [in that case you need to add an exception for the FB scraper, which can be identified by its User Agent.])

Comment: You have an example?

Comment: For what exactly? How to redirect, either using JS or server-side (with whatever language you are using there), should be easy enough to research. (And what User-Agent header the scraper sends, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo)